# Azure PowerShell certificate not specified

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to stop or start a Azure Virtual Machine with PowerShell. I am not very experienced in PowerShell so I wrote a simple script as a test:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"

$subID = "<GUID>"
$thumbprint = "<Thumbprint>"
$subscriptionName = "testAzure"
$myCert = Get-Item cert:\\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint
$vmName = "<vm name>"

Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $subscriptionName -SubscriptionId $subID -Certificate $myCer
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName

Get-AzureSubscription -Current
```

I created a .cer certificate on my pc which I exported and then imported in Azure (I used the exact example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg551722.aspx). When I Write-Host the $myCert variable I get a response:

> [Subject]   CN=testAzure
>
> [Issuer]   CN=testAzure
>
> [Serial Number]   --serialnumber--
>
> [Not Before]   29-6-2013 15:27:26
>
> [Not After]   1-1-2040 00:59:59
>
> [Thumbprint]   --thumbprint--

When I run the script I get the following error:

> Get-AzureSubscription : You MUST specify a certificate. Call
>   Set-AzureSubscription and Select-AzureSubscription first. At
>   D:\Users\foobar\Desktop\test.ps1:23 char:1
>   + Get-AzureSubscription -Current
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Subscription.GetAzureSubscriptionCommand

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong? Does anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your code:

```
Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $subscriptionName -SubscriptionId $subID -Certificate $myCer
```

You're specifying certificate variable in `Set-AzureSubscription` as **`$myCer`** where as the variable above is defined as **`$myCert`** (missing "t").

Comment: `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` is your friend. Get in the habit of making it the first line in all your scripts.

Comment: Haha oh my God, I've been struggling with this for hours. Thanks Gaurav Mantri